# Seeking little known book about landing on a distant planet and secretly integrating into alien society

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember much but the title was short and vague to the story while the cover of the book had either a planet or galaxy on it, giving it that sci-fi look.

A group of people become stranded when they land on an "Eden" type planet previously thought uninhabited by intelligent life. They are one of many ships sent out to inhabit other planets from Earth. Upon discovering a society of fairly intelligent life forms (their sole characteristic I recall described them as some how duck-like), the stranded study them and are able to fairly easily throw on some costumes and assume the role of newcomers to the town. I believe the leader has something needed to fix the ship or communicate with the other humans searching for a new planet to establish roots.

Apologies for being vague but can any one help??